# how to roll two arrays of diffeent dimesnions into one dimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays (a,b) of different mXn dimensions

I need to know that how can I roll these two arrays into a single one dimensional array

I used np.flatten() for both a,b array and then rolled them into a single array but what i get is an array containg two one dimensional array(a,b)

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7]]) #3x4 array
b = np.array([ [1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]) #5x2 array

result = [a.flatten(),b.flatten()]
print(result)
[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([1, 2, 2, 3, ... 5, 6])]
```

In matlab , I would do it like this :

```
res = [a(:);b(:)]
```

Also, how can I retrieve `a` and `b` back from the result?

Comment: Try `np.concatenate((a.ravel(), b.ravel()))`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ woah, simple! This workes

Comment: one more question, any idea how do get both array a and b after rolling them into one dimensional array?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. What is your expected output?

Comment: okay, [res = np.concatenate((a.ravel(), b.ravel()))] . now res is 1D array congaing both the elements of a,b. Now i need to get back my arrays a,b from res

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ravel` + `concatenate`:

```
>>> np.concatenate((a.ravel(), b.ravel()))
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6])
```

`ravel` returns a 1D view of the arrays, and is a cheap operation. `concatenate` joins the views together, returning a new array.

---

As an aside, if you want to be able to retrieve these arrays back, you'll need to store their shapes in some variable.

```
i = a.shape
j = b.shape
res = np.concatenate((a.ravel(), b.ravel()))
```

Later, to retrieve `a` and `b` from `res`,

```
a = res[:np.prod(i)].reshape(i)
b = res[np.prod(i):].reshape(j)

a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])

b 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 6]])
```

Answer (score -1):

How about changing the middle line to:

```
result = [a.flatten(),b.flatten()].flatten()
```

Or even more simply (if you know there's always exactly 2 arrays)

```
result = a.flatten() + b.flatten()
```

Comment: If you actually tried both you'll realize they both error out.

Comment: this doesn't work, because the result of this is an  list and list has no attribute called flatten()

Comment: ah, yep. result would need to be a new np.array. regardless, the above answer is cleaner.